# Node.JS Reload Python Script

Tags: python, node.js

I'm debugging a Node.JS program that uses the python-shell npm package to load Python scripts. Everything works great, but if I make a change to the Python script, then restart the node program, the changes to the Python script are not reflected at run time.

I did not find a way in python-shell API to force the reload of a script and most of the other google searches for this type of problem suggested forcing an import reload within the Python script.  But the Python script that is part of the program does not have an import of itself, so that won't work.

I also tried closing down the VSCode IDE environment in case that was somehow also caching the previous version of the script, but still no luck in seeing the changes.

Node Code snippet:
let x = new PythonShell( pb.py, { mode: 'text', pythonOptions: ['-u'], scriptPath: pythonPath(), args: ['hi','there']});

Python code snippet attempts to "reload" itself:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5PIq.png)

I can hack around the problem by renaming the "pb.py" file to something new and then update the node code to call out the new name.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding it, you are starting a script from node, and terminating the script when node exits, but when restarting node the old version of the script runs again?

Comment: Yep, and this is Python2.  I've tried putting "reload('theNameOfThePythonScriptHere') at the top of the python script, then renamed the script (to force a reload of course) and then changed my node code to call the new name of the script but that results in "reload argument must be module".  Hope that makes sense, just trying to re-run node with some new print statements in the python script and have the new statements show up.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to start the script?

Comment: edit your question rather than writing in the comments

Comment: SOLVED: there was an instance of the script that was running in the background due to some error-handling that wasn't cleaning up after itself.  That may be why it wasn't refreshing the python file.